# scrapy middleware file structure

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

I am learning scrapy and am trying to use middleware to send a processed jsp page to scrapy crawlspider. After I run `scrapy crawl pccprofile2`, no error or result returns. I suspect that the file structure is incorrect. I am probably missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My file structure loos like this:
[image]

My middlewares.py selects a specific value from the dropdown menu of the target [page](http://www.cppcc.gov.cn/CMS/icms/project1/cppcc/wylibary/wjWeiYuanList.jsp) and returns the url response. It contains the following class:

```
class JSMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.get('http://www.cppcc.gov.cn/CMS/icms/project1/cppcc/wylibary/wjWeiYuanList.jsp')
    more_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
         EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, '_button_select'))
                )
    more_btn.click()

    # select from the dropdown menu
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#tabJcwyxt_jiebie > option[value='teyaoxgrs']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#tabJcwyxt_jieci > option[value='d11jie']").click()
    search2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input_a2')
    search2.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    body = driver.page_source
    print body
    return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

The settings.py and the **init**.py in the spiders folder both contains the following lines:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'pccprofile2.middlewares.JSMiddleware': 543,
}
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'pccprofile2.middlewares.JSMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Finally, my spider_pccprofile2.py looks like this. It clicks into each item of the result table and save the information inside each link. After that, it clicks "next page" and do the same thing.

```
class ProfileSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'pccprofile2'
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='table']")), callback='parse_item')]  

def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []
    item = Ppcprofile2Item()
    item ["name"] = hxs.select("//h1/text()").extract()
    item ["title"] = hxs.select("//div[@id='contentbody']//tr//td//text()").extract()
    items.append(item)

    #click next page      
    while True:
        next = response.findElement(By.linkText("下一页"))
        try:
            next.click()
        except:
            break

    return(items)
```

Please let me know if there is something obvious that I am missing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your middleware class enabled in the settings? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware

Comment: added `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'pccprofile2.middlewares.JSMiddleware': 543,
}` to both the middlewares.py and __init__.py but still no result...

Comment: That setting needs to go in `settings.py`, as it's a Scrapy setting.

Comment: sorry yes, that was what i meant. i added that to the `settings.py` and init.py in the spiders. still nth.

Comment: could it be that I need to add a `start_url`  in the CrawlSpider? but since I want the `start_url` to be the response url from the middleware, how would I add that?

Comment: Yes, you need `start_urls` in the spider itself. The spider's `parse` method doesn't get called until after the downloader middlewares have run, but the spider definitely gets loaded before any middleware (otherwise `scrapy foo` would never know what spider was named "foo", right?).

Comment: thanks!! i replaced `webdriver.PhantomJS()` with `webdriver.Firefox()`. Now a new instance of Firefox (returning the information from the query) just keep opening. Nothing is scraped, however. I think the file structure is ok now. I just need to work on fixing the spider - the HtmlResponse is still not being passed to the spider.... But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the file is correct. The spider ran and multiple instances of firefox with the query result opened. The information is not scraped, however. This indicates that the problem lies in the spider specification in passing the response url to the spider.

Comment: Thanks for the solution that helps me a lot. Can you please elaborate the role of DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES here.@Onyi Lam